# For Loop causing panic: runtime error due to nil map or slice

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, indexing

Hey I am trying to create a simple scalar vector for my program.

I was starting with a simple variable and incrementing it to make it a 32 by 1 size vector matrix.

```
var x []int
for i := 0; i < 32 ; i++{
    x[i] = i + 1
}
```

Simple enough but when trying to compile this I get this error.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/jeanmac/go/src/matrices/main.go:69 +0x7d

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Not sure why. FYI Line 69 refers to `x[i] = i + 1`.
When trying to assign `x[i]` I receive the following warning.

`Reports indexing of nil map or slice that may lead to runtime panic.`

Not sure why this seems to be happening.

Comment: Have you gone through the Tour of Go? Specifically the [section on slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)? Or looked at the [Effective Go section on slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices)? Or the [documentation on making and appending to slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)? Or [Slices: Usage and Internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)? Or [Arrays Slices and Strings](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocate the slice. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := make([]int, 32)
    for i := range x {
        x[i] = i + 1
    }
    fmt.Println(x == nil, len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UVrUAZHtTw-

Output:

```
false 32 32 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32]
```

---

In your example, you have a zero-value (`nil`) slice which has length 0. Therefore, `x[i]` or `x[0]` is `panic: runtime error: index out of range`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x []int
    fmt.Println(x == nil, len(x), cap(x), x)
    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        x[i] = i + 1
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3hG5FpV3_dC

Output:

```
true 0 0 []
panic: runtime error: index out of range
main.go:9
```

---

References:

[A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

[Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)

[Making slices, maps and channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)